# Position:Sticky Not Working in CSS Squarespace

Tags: css, sticky, squarespace

Looking to have a block within the page stick when you scroll down

i.e. https://auratenewyork.com/

(Note: "Fine jewelry designed to be worthy of the women who wear it" text block sticks while the right side still scrolls)

`.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}`

This is to be a custom CSS code within squarespace. Sticky is just not working and it's wracking my brain. I've even changed the overflow to visible or auto (not hidden). Still doesn't work. Sticky does not even come up highlighted like position:fixed does.

Comment: Have you added the `sticky` class to the HTML element? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: the HTML is just <div class> = "sticky"> </div>

Comment: That's not valid HTML. There shouldn't be a `>` after `class`.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46) goes over how position sticky works. But since you haven't provided any code yet, we can only guess what the issue might be. But please note this part from the article:

> While playing with it, I quickly noticed that when an element with a position: sticky style is wrapped, and it is the only element inside the wrapper element, this element, which was defined position: sticky will not stick. [...] When I added more elements inside the wrapper element, it started working.

Hopefully this wil help you.